# Getting the associated tags with the text

Tags: javascript, html

I know I can extract the complete text from the HTML document using `document.body.innerText` as shown with the following snippet,

```js
console.log(document.body.innerText)
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="message">Hello, this is Amanda speaking ..</span>
  
  <span>Please follow the below <b class="emph">instructions</b> </span>
</p>
```

but how could I know the associated `tags`? For example, `Hello, this is Amanda speaking ..` is associated with the `span` tag with `id=message`. What I want to do this, get the text from each tag, pass it through some API and get the transformed text. Then I will put back the transformed text maintaining the same HTML structure. But with the current setup as shown above, I do not the associated tags.

Comment: You need to loop  all elements in block, for example
`Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*')).forEach(block=>doSome(block));`

Comment: @zb' Considering from a perspective, where I would want to continuously put back the transformed text into the respective tag, how will this work? For example, in my demo application https://vigorous-wilson-e04731.netlify.com/ , how must I go about continuously transforming the text and presenting it as the user browses?

Comment: I not understand, what means continuously here ?

Comment: @zb' I mean a dynamic behavior. For example in infinite scrolling, e-commerce websites etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `querySelectorAll()` and `map()`

```js
var tags = document.querySelectorAll('p *');
var res = Array.from(tags).map(el => ({tag: el.tagName, text: el.innerText}));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="message">Hello, this is Amanda speaking ..</span>
  
  <span>Please follow the below <b class="emph">instructions</b> </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Considering from a perspective, where I would want to continuously put back the transformed text into the respective tag, how will this work? For example, in my demo application https://vigorous-wilson-e04731.netlify.com/ , how must I go about continuously transforming the text and presenting it as the user browses?